# Syntax error on token "fav_up_btn1", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Tags: java, android, syntax-error

I'm getting a few errors in eclipse stating:

```
Syntax error on token "fav_up_btn1", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token Home.java   /idg/src/com/idg/omv    line 508    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration   Home.java   /idg/src/com/idg/omv    line 508    Java Problem
Syntax error on token ")", { expected after this token  Home.java   /idg/src/com/idg/omv    line 508    Java Problem
Return type for the method is missing   Home.java   /idg/src/com/idg/omv    line 508    Java Problem
Syntax error on token ".", ... expected Home.java   /idg/src/com/idg/omv    line 508    Java Problem
```

I'm unsure exactly why this is happening. If any additional information is required I will be more than happy to provide it.

### JAVA:

```
fav_up_btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);

fav_up_btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean favIsUp = fav_up_btn1
                .getBackground()
                .getConstantState()
                .equals(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.fav_up_btn1).getConstantState());
        // set the background
        fav_up_btn1
        .setBackgroundResource(favIsUp ? R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn1
                : R.drawable.fav_up_btn1);
    }
});
```

### FULL SOURCE:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bbcDKDL3UatzK8Gox6aHKi5_Zw-IEwan_Qu4Em8CNmg/edit

Comment: what line is , line 508 in your code ?

Comment: fav_up_btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);

Comment: Any suggestions? I posted my full source just in case this isn't enough...

Comment: Can you post your full logcat output?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialize a variable in the middle of a class.

Line 508 is in the middle of an inner class definition, you won't be able to initialize variables there (or set listeners, or almost anything really).

You probably want to move that code (and the code for all of your `youTubeThumbnailView`s) into your `onInitializationSuccess` (I'm just guessing at this exact location, but they will need to be inside some block of code rather than just hanging out in the middle of a class body).

---

Edit: full source was in a private Google Document when this answer was posted

`Button fav_up_btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);`

You need to declare the type of fav_up_btn1.

Comment: Changing just that line causes me to go from 5 errors (shown above) to 39 (Mostly: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field mainScrollView)

Comment: Please post your enough of your code to help us.  Your Google Docs link is private.

Comment: Apologies - I updated it to be public (thank you for your assistance - I REALLY need help with this!)